# Reloading a datatable with values from database

Tags: java, primefaces

I currently have a data table that displays a list of Users obtained from my database (Users Table). My application allows me to do the following:

- Select a Group
- Select a User
- Add
- UserGroups datatable displays the Group and User that was added.

The User that is added, will not be displayed in the User data table -- meaning to say, it is only in the view that the user will not be displayed. However, the user still exists in the database table.

(This is happening in my web view)

For example:

```
Group:

 1. Web
 2. Projects
 3. Management

User:

 1. Tom
 2. Jane
 3. John
```

I select 1 group and 1 user, and add it to the User Group.

```
UserGroup:

 1. Management, John
```

AND User and Group tables shows the following:

Group:

```
 1. Web
 2. Projects
 3. Management
```

User:

```
 1. Tom
 2. Jane
```

How would I refresh the User table, so that I can obtain a new list of Users from my database for another round of selection ?? because once I add all the Users, the User table is empty, and I want the User datatable to refresh, when I click on a new Group for selection.

Any clues or suggestions on how I might go about doing so... I am clueless.

I currently have the following methods in my managedBean:

My methods for retrieving a list of Users, Groups and UserGroups.

```
 public List<Usuarious> getListOfUsuarios() throws DAOExceptions{
        List<Usuarious> usuariosList = userDAO.list();
        listOfUsuarios = usuariosList;
        return listOfUsuarios;
    }

    public List<Grupos> getListOfGrps() throws DAOExceptions {
        List<Grupos> grpList = grpDAO.list();
        listOfGrps = grpList;
        return listOfGrps;
    }

    public List<UsuariousGrupos> getListOfUserGroups() throws DAOExceptions{
        List<UsuariousGrupos> usuariosGruposList = userGrpDAO.list(var2);
        listOfUserGroups = usuariosGruposList;
        return listOfUserGroups;
    }
```

I thought of just creating a refreshList() method:

```
   public void refreshList() throws DAOExceptions{
        listOfUsuarios = getListOfUsuarios();
    }
```

And then adding it to my finishAddUser() method list to refresh the datatable:

```
   public void finishAddUsuariosGrupos()throws DAOExceptions {
        this.userGroups.setId_grupo(var2);
        this.userGroups.setId_usuario(var1);
        userGrpDAO.create(userGroups);
        refreshList();

    }
```

But it is not working out.

Comment: if you already have some implementation and you want something more, show us what you already have...

Comment: yeah I've added some of my code

Comment: xhtml code too...by the way the method `refreshList` is useless - you assign the same object to `listOfUsuarios`...you could use directly the method `getListOfUsuarios`

Comment: Sounds like as `userGrpDAO.create()` and `userDAO.list()` runs in different transactions and that they are only committed by end of response (or probably never). What kind of persistence are you using? JPA? Hibernate? Plain JDBC? This is after all not a JSF problem.

Comment: Also, BalusC, I followed your tutorial on the blog to create the create() and list() methods for my JDBC DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar datatable refresh issue. I solved it by adding settimeout to the datatable:

```
<webuijsf:table onClick="setTimeout('#{user$reports.updateGeneratedReportList()}',500);"/>
```

updateGeneratedReportList is method is equal to your refreshList method.

Comment: OP isn't using Woodstock. OP is using PrimeFaces. Component library specific approaches doesn't necessarily work for other component libraries.

Comment: This is note the way...once you use Primefaces, you can take advantage of all it's power~

Comment: yes I am using PrimeFaces. Do u mean I can make use of the tags to refresh it in my view??

Comment: I thought a simple JS may work in other component libraries.. or may be it doesn't.